# DynamoDB Model/Keys Advice

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I was hoping someone could help me understand how to best design my table(s) for DynamoDb. I'm building an application which is used to track the visits a certain user makes to another user's profile.

Currently I have a MongoDB where one entry contains the following fields:

- userId
- visitedProfileId
- date
- status
- isMobile

How would this translate to DynamoDB in a way it would not be too slow? I would need to do search queries to select all items that have a certain userId, taking the status and isMobile in affect. What would me keys be? Can I use limit functionality to only request the latest x entries (sorted on date?).

I really like the way DynamoDB can be used but it really seems kind of complicated to make the click between a regular NoSQL database and a key-value nosql database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this - and it probably depends on any other querying you may want to do on this table.

1. Make your `HashKey` of the table the `userId`, and then the `RangeKey` can be `<status>:<isMobile>:<date>` (eg `active:true:2013-03-25T04:05:06.789Z`). Then you can [query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Query.html) using `BEGINS_WITH` in the `RangeKeyCondition` (and `ScanIndexForward` set to `false` to return in ascending order).

   So let's say you wanted to find the 20 most recent rows of user ID `1234abcd` that have a `status` of `active` and an `isMobile` of `true` (I'm guessing that's what you mean by "taking [them] into affect"), then your [query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Query.html) would look like:

   ```
   {
     "TableName": "Users",
     "Limit": 20,
     "HashKeyValue": { "S": "1234abcd" },
     "RangeKeyCondition": {
       "ComparisonOperator": "BEGINS_WITH"
       "AttributeValueList": [{ "S": "active:true:" }],
     },
     "ScanIndexForward": false
   }
   ```
2. Another way would be to make the `HashKey` `<userId>:<status>:<isMobile>`, and the `RangeKey` would just be the `date`. You wouldn't need a `RangeKeyCondition` in this case (and in the example, the `HashKeyValue` would be `{ "S": "1234abcd:active:true" }`).